# Apache2 | http.conf How do I set AllowOverride All on a directory

Tags: debian, apache-http-server, debian-wheezy, httpd

I have to set `AllowOveride` to `All` on my web server, but in my `httpd.conf` file, there is no `<Directory>` tag for me to place it in.

I never seen this before. What can I do? Where is the file I have to change?

I am on a LAMP server, and Debian7, with Apache2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file that you are looking for is probably in **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf** or similar.

You can create the Directory tags yourself in /etc/httpd.conf, /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf, or in a new file placed in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/**example**.conf

Below is what you need to include in one of the files mentioned above:

```
<Directory /path/to/directory-name>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Apache will load this directory block from any of the configuration files. I imagine that you are probably used to putting this in the default block that had previously been located in the /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file. The default DocumentRoot and Directory tags still exist but are probably located in /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf.

You may also consider creating a new configuration file for your specific website in /etc/apache2/sites-available/**example**.conf. Then placing within that file, something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName site-name.com
ServerAlias other-name.com www.site-name.com
DocumentRoot /path/to/application
    <Directory />
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

By default Apache will load configuration from any file that is located in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/* that ends in `.conf`

Comment: At least on debian there is command `a2ensite` which will make the symlink from `sites-available` to `sites-enabled` for you (but you can make it also manually).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Only one thing that I noticed. The `000-default` file should have an `.conf` extension, right?

Comment: yes, if you look inside httpd.conf you will see that near the bottom, there is: Include sites-enabled/*.conf You could ofc change that so that any file will be loaded in. You can also manually include any file: Include /path/to/file